# I can't switch to form while Selenium chrome is running

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I click but it doesn't open.Waiting for the boat running in Selenium to end

Comment: Can you please describe your case with a code snippet that you are using.

Comment: How so ? which part do you want?